# Arduino UNO as socket client - Lan ok, Wan is not

Tags: arduino

So I have a simple EchoServer written in java. 
I also have an echo client on the Arduino Uno, and everything works fine on my LAN.
If I put the server onto the internet (a private VM), I can use standard telnet to reach it, but when I run the Arduino, it produces 'Connection failed', when using the external IP.
To repeat, I can reach the external IP using a standard telnet client.
I cannot think what it could be, anybody had a similar problem
thanks in advance

Comment: DHCP or static IP on Uno? is the gateway address right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Juraj
I needed to set dns adress and gateway !!

```
byte mac[] = {  
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,177);
IPAddress dnsaddress(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,254);
 Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dnsaddress, gateway);
```

Comment: so you could add to question what was it before. `begin(mac, ip)` uses the supplied ip address to guess the dns and getaway address as ending with .1. your gateway address is unusual.

Comment: then the IP address of you router is unusual. and the DNS address?